# I can't see <img> tag inside <a> tag using Thymeleaf

Tags: html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm using th:each in order to show a list of clickable images, this is my template

```
            <!DOCTYPE html>
              <body>
                <ul>
                    <li th:each="opera : ${opere}">
                        <a href="artista.html" 
                           th:href="@{'/opera' + '/' + ${opera.id}}" 
                           th:text="${opera.nome}">
                           <img th:src="${opera.path}"/>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul> 
              </body>
            </html>
```

Normally, without the th:each attribute, it works fine but this way it shows only the link in `<a>` tag ignoring what's inside, I can't see it neither in chrome dev tools it's just like it isn't there. Could someone help me? Thanks.

Comment: See the linked answer.  `th:text` overwrites everything in it, so you have to move your `th:text` to a sibling tag of your `img`.

Comment: wow it was that simple? I spent a whole day on it ahhah. Now it works, thank u so much

Comment: I don't know how to give you the best answer since this is a comment and not an answer

Comment: @DelfinoDeChicchis - you can vote for the duplicate answer, if it resolved your problem, and if you have enough reputation points to do so. Accepting answers and voting are always completely optional - but are very helpful.